# Binary addition doesn't pass all tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

> Implement a function that adds two numbers together and returns their sum in binary. The conversion can be done before, or after the addition.
>
> The binary number returned should be a string.
>
> Examples: (Input1, Input2 --> Output (explanation))
>
> 1, 1 --> "10" (1 + 1 = 2 in decimal or 10 in binary)

```
import math

def add_binary(a,b):
    n = a + b
    binary = ''
    while n > 0:
        if n <= 1:
            binary += '1'
        if n > 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                binary += '0'
            if n % 2 != 0:
                binary += '1'
        n = math.floor(n / 2)
    return binary[::-1]
```

Examples of ones that didn't pass:

```
add_binary(90496199081781832257222786108, 11950991938878268526568196103)
add_binary(85987079672838407254875, 88106917934426688740141)
add_binary(6923177883455821141397787, 2519224062931874330334785)
```

Examples of ones that snuck by:

```
add_binary(62880022684, 72004557123)
add_binary(74525217235, 594777288464)
add_binary(997659049134380, 757610766652057)
```

This passed for 33 but failed for 17. I think it has to do with the numbers getting bigger but that's all I can really think of.

Comment: perhaps `f"{a+b:b}"` ?

Comment: In the posted code sample `while` loop will either not run or run forever since there is no change of the `n` value.

Comment: @PM77-1 What are you talking about? `n = math.floor(n / 2)` changes the value of `n`.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano That would not be helpful as this question is obviously about a homework designed to make students practice the actual implementation of a binary conversion.

Comment: @blhsing - At the time I posted my comment indentation was different and the statement was not inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your implementation does not work for large numbers is because of [floating-point rounding error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) resulted from conversion of a number with a precision requirement higher than what the binary encoding allows. And the reason you have a floating-point conversion issue in the first place is because you're using the [true division](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/#semantics-of-true-division) operator (`/`) to divide the number by 2 in each iteration, which converts both operands to floating-point numbers first before performing a division, which makes large numbers lose information.

You can remedy the issue by using the [floor division](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/#semantics-of-floor-division) operator (`//`) instead.

That is, change:

```
n = math.floor(n / 2)
```

to:

```
n = n // 2
```

Furthermore, by checking if n > 0 at the start of each iteration you would miss adding an output when n is 0 to begin with. Instead, perform the check at the end of the loop:

```
def add_binary(a, b):
    bits = []
    n = a + b
    while True:
        bits.append(n % 2)
        n //= 2
        if n == 0:
            break
    return ''.join(map(str, reversed(bits)))
```

Answer (score 0):

so just for an easy solution using in build python functions
(`bin` converts to binary, `str` casts as a string, `[2:]` strips of the 0b at the start)

```
def add_binary(a,b):
    return str(bin(a+b))[2:]
```

Currently your loop for loop doesn't work because `n` doesn't change in the while loop.

If you change the math.floor division to `n//2` that seemed to fix it on my end too. might be a weird floating point number that wasn't playing nice.

Comment: Please upvote, and select as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the python `bin` function? It converts python integers int to a binary (base 2) string. So you can do this:

```py
number1 = 30 # fill in this value
number2 = 20 # fill in this value
output=bin(number1+number2).lstrip("0b")
```

If you desperatly need a function, the following can do:

```py
add_binary = lambda a, b: bin(a+b).lstrip("0b")
def add_binary(a: int, b: int) -> str: return bin(a+b).lstrip("0b")
```

To break it down, `bin` does the conversion to a binary (returns a string, same as your example code), but it returns `0b10101010...`. Then `.lstrip` removes the 0b from the start.

Comment: " It converts decimal (base 10) int to a binary" `int` objets are not base 10. important to understand, `int` objects aren't base 10 in any sense, other than that's how they are printed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Short, sweet, simple:

```py
def add_binary(a,b):
    return f"{a+b:b}"
```

No need to remove `0b` prefixes: the `:b` format specifier outputs in binary without a prefix.